# How to get url and description of FileFieldItemList's items in node template

Tags: 8, theming

I have a content type called publication which results the node's twig template: `node--publication.html.twig`.
This content type contains a multiple file fields where the description is allowed.

I would like to share it with you, because it took a lot of time for me to find out how can I iterate through and render the items of a `FileFieldItemList` which would be a very easy thing without the drupal theming system.

Some of you might find useful it.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to access the `uri`, and I can generate url from it by a Twig filter.

```
{{ content.field_document.0['#file'].uri.value|urlFromUri }}
{{ content.field_document.1['#file'].uri.value|urlFromUri }}
{{ content.field_document.2['#file'].uri.value|urlFromUri }}
```

and the `description`:

```
{{ content.field_document.0['#description'] }}
{{ content.field_document.1['#description'] }}
{{ content.field_document.2['#description'] }}
```

the Twig filter:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\something_general\TwigExtension;

use Drupal\Core\Url;


class Custom extends \Twig_Extension
{

  /**
   * Generates a list of all Twig filters that this extension defines.
   */
  public function getFilters()
  {
    return [
      new \Twig_SimpleFilter('urlFromUri', array($this, 'UrlFromUri')),
    ];
  }


  /**
   * Gets a unique identifier for this Twig extension.
   */
  public function getName()
  {
    return 'custom.something_general.twig_extension';
  }


  /**
   * @param $uri
   */
  public static function UrlFromUri($uri)
  {
    $realpath = drupal_realpath($uri);
    $path = str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], '', $realpath);

    return $path;
  }

}
```

I am also able, to get the number of the items of the `FileFieldItemList`:

```
{% for index in 1..node.field_document.getValue|length %}
{% endfor %}
```

And finally the iteration in the `node--publication.html.twig` file:

```
{% for index in 1..node.field_document.getValue|length %}
  {% set document = content.field_document[ (index-1) ] %}

  {{ dump(document['#file'].uri.value|urlFromUri) }}
  {{ dump(document['#description']) }}

{% endfor %}
```